# Git asking ssh credentials for https repo

Tags: git, github

I've got a git repository on my local network. Repository was configured to use https. When I've typed commands like
**git fetch**, **git push** etc it always asked for credentials via console. 
Not so long ago I've cloned a github repository to my PC and after that each request to my local server asks me for ssh credentials also after each merge git asks me to enter merge message. It looks like something have change in git config after cloning github repository. I've cheched gitconfig but found nothing. Please help to find out what have caused such strange git behaviour

.git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://mysupertfs.repo.ru/RepoTest/_git/Rep 
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "Remastered"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/npaRemastered
```

Comment: Can you please share your .git/config with us?

Comment: @Anton, that is very hard to read. Instead of adding a comment, please use the **edit** link to the bottom-left of your question and add your config there.